# iPad Input accessory View on a ViewController displayed as a form

Tags: ios, ipad, inputaccessoryview

Ive been searching for awhile on this issue and I cant seem to find an answer. Im looking to use a Input accessory view on a view controller that is displayed on the iPad as a form sheet. I currently have the ALTextInputBar implemented that works well but my problem is that the accessory view is displayed full screen width. Id like to apply the input accessory to the displayed modal VC only. Like facebook has implemented in their iPad app below.

[image]

So my commentsVC code has the following methods

```
var messageInput = ALTextInputBar()
let keyboardObserver = ALKeyboardObservingView()
let leftButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44))
let rightButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44))

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    get {
        return messageInput
    }
}

override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

I then configure the textInputbar in its own method setting the left and right buttons etc. This all works perfect, Its just Id like to have the same approach as the image above.

One approach I have tried but it doesnt work too well is setting the tablefooterview of the commentsVc to equal messageInput. Although this is very buggy and not the right approach imo.

Comment: Got this awhile ago, just updating what I did for anyone else who comes across this. I have created my own custom approach to this using a UIViewController and manipulating the preferredContentSize of the viewController displayed depending on the keyboard being shown. I also pinned the ALTextInputBar inside a toolbar at the bottom of the viewcontroller so the effect is the same. Works really well